How to manage Page elements in Angular 19 in the right way?
I am trying to learn Angular 19. Every thing was pretty good until i started trying to manipulate the elements on the Page. I hope someone will help me to understand the idea of it in Angular.
Example

I have list on page and i just want to add and remove new items of this list

List of fruits +

apple x
banana x

On pressing + i want add new item to the end of the list (the name of item or another content does not matter, just add new item).
On pressing x i want to delete corresponding item from the list.
in JavaScript
If i need to change page structure using native JavaScript, i must use:

document.querySelector()
node.append()
node.remove()
and so on...
this tools allow me to create, add, remove and change HTML elements.

So i must:
// this is simple example without using classes

let list = document.querySelector('.listOfFruits');
let newItem= document.createElement('li');
newItem.innerHTML = 'orange';

list.append(newItem);

//another code to remove item and so own

in Angular 19
What should i use?
I learned:

@if
@for
NgComponentOutlet
ViewContainerRef

But it is not seems to be the right way to do what i want to do. And i can not find any other information in Docs with full explanation how this kind of things has to be done in Angular.
Someone, please, give me full explanation.
Thank you.

I think @if and @for is the right way to achieve your goals, why do you think otherwise? You should store the list in an array and iterate over that array in the template using @for. For example, check this tutorial from the official docs. By manipulating the array you can add or remove items from the DOM.

i think otherwise because using @for force me to use data. Native JS allow me manage the page no matter do i have data or not. What if i want to add more structure on page without data? Just add empty rows in table or empty items in list, like in my example?
I just want to undestand conception.

It's much easier to separate data and view.  (model view controller) Angular will do change detection for you, so it's very simple.  What you are describing is having the view hold the data (DOM), which complicates things a little and can become harder to manage when you start adding features.  Angular separates the view and the data... you can then put most of the logic in the controller (.ts file) though some view-related logic will be in the "view" which is more of a dynamic template than a traditional view.

@browsermator , you want to say, that Angular designed to work with dynamic template via data? And all tasks in that "category" can be done via @if and @for directives?

if you update the data in your controller (.ts file for the component), Angular's change-detection kicks in and updates the view.  (your @ if's and @ for's will run again)
